# CSS Flexbox: How do I resize a fixed size image while retaining the aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a fixed size image, let's say 800px(w) 800px(h). When I shrink the browser down, I want my image to maintain the aspect ratio. How can I achieve that with flexbox? Is that even possible? Browsers compatibility isn't an issue.

Here is my codepen.
http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/xEKzD

Or do I have to resort to @media queries,or  element?

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" alt="" class="child" />
</div>

.parent{
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: check this link [http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/g6g87ay7/ ]

Comment: So simple! You are genius! But yea, need a max-width as mentioned below.

Comment: I somehow thinks that answer by @yugi is good. The other accepted answer has properties which are deprecated now.

Comment: @RohitKandhal You will have to use max-width:100% instead of width:100% as mentioned by yugi if not the 800px 800px image will fill up whatever screen size you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your css

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;  
    align-items: center;
}

img {max-width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .child{
   max-width:800px;
   width:100%
   height:auto;
   }
```